# Comparing request module vs selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I made a program that works with **selenium**, and it automates for posting comment to the some blogs' contents. I'm not familiar with the **requests** module of python. (working on it for just a week) The thing that I'm wondering is, my program with selenium is a bit slow for page loading, and **it loads everything from ads to the images/videos**. If I'd made my program with requests module, would it save data and a bit faster according to the selenium module?

I searched this issue at some forum-sites, generally they say request modules a bit faster, but not all. Also I couldn't find any info about saving data by comparing this modules?

*Plz don't give me directly the thumbs down. I need this answer with details.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium is used for **web automation** via clicking in web elements and sending keys to input boxes.

**To speed up selenium, use *headless mode*, so that the visual components like ads are not loaded and the work is fast** , go to selenium's documentation to learn more about headless mode.

While requests is used for **HTTP methods**
Like GET, POST etc. Learn more about requests from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_requests.asp)

If the blogging site has a public api, then you can use requests module.

If you are new to API , I recommend watching this YouTube video
https://youtu.be/GZvSYJDk-us

For example to create issues on GitHub you can use GitHub API.

*But to comment on a blogging site which has no public api, you need to use selenium*.

**Requests directly send and receive data from the server which hosts a particular service, so it is fast**.

But selenium interacts with the web browser.

*When you are using requests , you can do an action directly, without having to perform a bunch of clicks or send keys*.

Comment: The forum site that I'm sending comments does not have an API, so then I should continue with the selenium then. Actually, I just wanted to reduce spending data with selenium, because the forums have so many ads and visuals.

Comment: I know the headless mode, and used before. But I didn't know it makes a difference about saving data. I'll try and infrom you about the difference

Comment: Headless will not load visual components. It speeds up things

Comment: I used headless chrome a few times before, but didnt know this feature. It halved the spending data mate. Thanks :)

Comment: According to stack overflow community guidelines, comments are for clarification .
To say thanks you can upvote ^ an answer or if it is the best answer accept it by clicking on the tick mark

Answer (score 0):

Selenium allows you to control a browser and execute actions on a webpage.

requests library is for making HTTP requests.

So, if you know how to write your program for posting comments with just using HTTP API then I’d go with requests, Selenium would be an overhead in this case

Comment: Thx for your answer firstly. As I said in the question, I'm just a newbie on requests module. Just know the logic how that works. To make a comment, the website must have an API? Because I've seen examples with REST APIs. Or every sites have an API? As far as I saw about my web-site, it doesn't have an REST API.

Comment: Pretty much all sites have http APIs, not necessarily REST APIs though.

Comment: You should search if the site you’re using has its apis documented somewhere

Comment: Not all websites make their APIs documented for public, in this case Selenium is a good workaround

Answer (score 0):

If you are proficient with HTTP requests and verb (know how to make a POST request to a server with `requests` library), then choose `requests`. If you want to test your script, use `selenium` or `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Can I send comments and login to the forum without an API. Beacuse, my web-sites doesn't have APIs. And there is no login page, its javascript button as far as I saw in the Inspect(F12) of chrome

Comment: If the website has an API endpoint, yes you can go with `requests` module. If there aren't any endpoints, you should use selenium